# Is an upvote of a vote-to-close comment counted as a vote-to-close?

Tags: support, comments, flags, vote-to-close, automatic-comments

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34678530/loop-with-application-ontime) I agreed on the closing vote:

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its better suited for Code Review

Using the normal way to flag for closing I would choose: *Flag > Closing > Off-Topic > This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network*. However this site, [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), is not listed there. 
If there were no comment before, I would have used *Flag > ￼ in need of moderator intervention*.

**Is it sufficient to do an upvote of this vote to close comment?** I.e. will the upvote be counted as a vote to close?

I mention this because in the review process the votes to close automatically generate a comment, and if it already exists upvote it.

Comment: You don't have sufficient rep on SO to [VTC](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions), which doesn't come until 3K rep. You can flag and put something into the CV queue but if it's already got a VTC, your upvote doesn't really mean anything. Regardless, the question is interesting in general.

Comment: @Catija: thanks, this makes it clear to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Using the normal way to flag for closing I would choose: *Flag > Closing > Off-Topic > This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network*. However this site, [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), is not listed there. 
>   If there were no comment before, I would have used *Flag > ￼ in need of moderator intervention*.

First of all, voting / flagging for migration does **not** generate comments. Nor does flagging for moderator intervention. (you know this possibly, just noticing). Such comment is produced when you vote to close with a custom reason, which is only available for 3k+ users (there's no possibility to *flag* a question as off-topic with a custom reason).

> [image]

> Is it sufficient to do an upvote of this vote to close comment? I.e. will the upvote be counted as a vote to close?

No, it doesn't work reversed. The vote is recorded only if, again, you have 3k, open the window and choose the custom option already chosen by another user. And in this case, the comment will be automatically upvoted.

This also applies to the automatic duplicate comments. Unlike custom-close-reason-comments, a user can trigger the dupe-comment auto-generation since only 50 rep (that's the rep since which you can flag as dupe).

Answer (score 6):

No, upvoting a close comment does not record a vote/flag to close.

To ease your confusion, that user didn't vote to migrate - you simply can't do that for any site not in that list. What they *did* do, was write a custom off-topic close reason suggesting that the user ask there. You can see it as an option at the bottom of the first off-topic screen (prefixed with "Other"). This might not show up for users who can only flag, as they can't enter custom off-topic reasons.